# SwiftUI - EnvironmentObject - Strange Memory Usage

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I've got some strange results with the memory usage in my SwiftUI App. Below you see a minimal example I've build.

```swift
/// Test file for strange behaviour with EnvironmentObject
/// The RAM Usage is increased if we click the button in View "Settings" and switch back to "MapView"

import SwiftUI
import MapKit

class Model: ObservableObject {
    @Published var coolBool: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            print(coolBool.description)
        }
    }
}

struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    private let mapView = MKMapView(frame: .zero)
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        return mapView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {

    }
}

struct Settings: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            Button(action: {self.model.coolBool.toggle()}) {
                Text(self.model.coolBool.description)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var model: Model
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView() {
            MapView().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "map")
                Text("1")
            }
            Settings().tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "gear")
                Text("2")
            }
            Text("Just a screen").tabItem {
                Image(systemName: "sunrise")
                Text("3")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Scenario:

1. Open App
2. You will see **MapView**, the memory usage is stable
3. Go to Tab **2**
4. Click the button which will change the **EnvironmentObject**, memory usage still stable
5. Go to Tab **3**, memory usage is the same
6. Go to Tab **1** (MapView), memory usage is increased

If you redo 3, 4, 6 you will see that the memory usage is going bigger and bigger.
Can someone explain this to me?
The memory usage will start at ~40 MB, if I tap the button -> go to **MapView** -> tap the button -> go to **MapView** -> ....   the memory usage will increase. I got a memory usage of ~500 MB

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        MKMapView(frame: .zero)        // created here is managed by SwiftUI
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {

    }
}
```

**Alternate:** if you definitely want the one map view - use static

```
struct MapView: UIViewRepresentable {
    private let static mapView = MKMapView(frame: .zero)
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MKMapView {
        MapView.mapView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MKMapView, context: Context) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's like the SwiftUI Tutorial from Apple. My problem is then: If you switch the View the Map will reset. If you switch back to the MapView then you will miss the zoom level etc. which the user had. One solution would be to  mark all necessary variables with @Stable in the parent view and bind them to MapView. But it seems very ugly